# Populate text in empty rows above in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below is an example dataframe using Pandas. Sorry about the table format.
I would like to take the text 'RF-543' in column 'Test Case' and populate it in the two empty rows above it.
Likewise for text 'RT-483' in column 'Test Case', I would like to be populate it in the three empty rows above it.
I have over 900 rows of data with varying empty rows to be populated with the next non-empty row that follows. Any suggestions are appreciated.

| Req# | Test Case |
| --- | --- |
| 745 | AB-003 |
| 348 | AA-006 |
| 932 |  |
| 335 |  |
| 675 | RF-543 |
| 348 |  |
| 988 |  |
| 444 |  |
| 124 | RT-483 |

Regards,
Gus

Comment: `df.replace('',np.nan).bfill()`

Answer (score 1):

If they are NaN something as below:

### Creating dataframe test

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["apple",np.nan, np.nan, "banana", np.nan, "grape"]})
>>> df
        A
0   apple
1     NaN
2     NaN
3  banana
4     NaN
5   grape
```

### Use [fillna] method

```
>>> df["A"].fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)

>>> df
0     apple
1    banana
2    banana
3    banana
4     grape
5     grape
Name: A, dtype: object
```

If the fields are empty:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["apple", "", "", "banana", "", "grape"]})

>>> df
        A
0   apple
1
2
3  banana
4
5   grape

>>> df = df.apply(lambda x: x["A"] if x["A"] != "" else np.nan, axis=1)

>>> df
0     apple
1       NaN
2       NaN
3    banana
4       NaN
5     grape
dtype: object
```

Then, use the `fillna()`

Comment: Thank you Paulo. Your lines of code worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
df.loc[df["Test Case"] == '', "Test Case"] = np.nan
df.bfill()
```

**Output**

```
    Req# Test Case
0    745    AB-003
1    348    AA-006
2    932    RF-543
3    335    RF-543
4    675    RF-543
5    348    RT-483
6    988    RT-483
7    444    RT-483
8    124    RT-483
```